# Typescript filter no signatures

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript error that say .filter no signatures. I am not sure how to fix this

```
interface IDevice {
    deviceId: string;
    deviceName?: string;
}

const joinRoom = ({ userId, deviceId, deviceName }: IRoomParams) => {
  rooms[userId] = rooms[userId]?.filter((id) => id !== deviceId);
})
```

Update: below I added all of my interface and the full function for joining a room. I am not sure how to structure my types so that I can use .filter to remote device from the list when device disconnects

```
const rooms: Record<string, Record<string, IDevice>> = {};
interface IDevice {
    deviceId: string;
    deviceName?: string;
}
interface IRoomParams extends IDevice {
    userId: string;
}

interface ISendRequestParams {
    userId: string;
    options: any;
    requestId: string;
}

interface IReturnRequestParams {
    userId: string;
    data: any;
    requestId: string;
    error: any;
}

const joinRoom = ({ userId, deviceId, deviceName }: IRoomParams) => {
    if (!rooms[userId]) rooms[userId] = {};
    // console.log('device joined the room', userId, deviceId, deviceName);
    rooms[userId][deviceId] = { deviceId, deviceName };
    socket.join(userId);
    
    io.sockets.to(userId).emit('get-devices', {
        userId,
        participants: rooms[userId]
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`user left the room: roomId[${userId}], device[${deviceId}], deviceName[${deviceName}]`);
        rooms[userId] = rooms[userId]?.filter((id) => id !== deviceId);
        socket.to(userId).emit('device-disconnected', deviceName);
    });
};
```

error:
This expression is not callable.
Type 'IDevice' has no call signatures.ts(2349)

Comment: What's the type of `rooms`? What's `IRoomParams`? **If** we assume that `deviceId` in `IRoomParams` is `string` like it is in `IDevice`, the code is written such that `rooms[userId]` would need to have the type `undefined | string[]` (or `null | string[]`, or all three). Does it?

Comment: Can you provide more code please ? What is rooms (and it's type) ? what is IRoomParams ? this error usually occurs when you use `.filter` on object instead of array

Comment: When asking about error messages, please be sure to copy and paste the full error message into the question. Just "no signatures" doesn't really tell us much (*something*, but not much).

Comment: I updated question to reflect full function for joining a room and the full error message

Comment: Thanks for that! The type of `rooms[userId]` is `undefined | Record<string, IDevice>`, which is not an array type as @Paul-Marie said. You use `filter` on *arrays*, not simple objects.

Comment: Thank you all. I was able to fix the typescript error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to *remove* the `deviceId` from your Record (dictionary) of devices associated to a `userId`, you can just use the [`delete` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> The `delete` operator removes a property from an object.

```
delete rooms[userId][deviceId];
```

Comment: Thank you. I will accept your answer. Although I had issue with typescript your answer did cover the task which was to simply delete the object. Thank you